# C++11 Compilation Error for enumerated type declaration as expected } before numeric constant

Tags: linux, c++11, enums, compiler-errors, g++4.9

I have the following source file (`test.c`):

```
#include <iostream>
enum ecodes { ENOKEY = -1, EDUPKEY = -2 };
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile `without -std=c++11` it compiles fine.

```
g++  test.c -o test
```

When compiled with `-std=c++11`, it comes with compilation error:
g++ -std=c++11 test.c -o test

```
test.c:3:16: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
  enum ecodes { ENOKEY = -1, EDUPKEY = -2 };
                ^
test.c:3:16: error: expected â}â before numeric constant
test.c:3:16: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
test.c:3:42: error: expected declaration before â}â token
  enum ecodes { ENOKEY = -1, EDUPKEY = -2 };
```

Compiler used is GNU g++ 4.9.2 on Linux.

```
bash-4.2$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)
```

Please help.

Comment: `C++11` for a C program? You sure about that? Seriously C++03, C++11, and C differ in their implementation of `enum`s, so you do need to clarify.

Comment: Compiles OK for me with g++ 4.9.2 - I'm guessing there's a name conflict (macro?) in a header somewhere. I think we need a [mcve]...

Comment: @Bathsheba I have put a minimal example from a gigantic codebase where I face the problem. The codebase is mostly C++ but have some .c files as well having this example as given

Comment: @PaulR Agreed. But when I compile the file as g++ src.c, it compiles ok, but when I compile as g++ -std=c++11 src.c, it gets compilation error. If this was due to name conflict (I also thought that), wouldn't that be also for g++ src.c?

Comment: Methinks we need to see the smallest body of code that exhibits the problem. The enum above is a valid statement in C and C++, so currently it's anyone's guess what the problem is.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, you are right. I am too confused, the statement seems to be 100% correct. There is no repetition of same symbol, but same header file might be getting included more than once, my guess, will double-check and post after the finding.

Comment: @Bathsheba I have edited my question with a minimal complete example, there is no double inclusion of any file. Are the enumerated symbol clashing with predefined symbols on Linux? But why only with C++11 flag?

Comment: Hum. Could you humour me and drop the `using namespace std;` (which is a little naughty anyway). I wonder if the gcc C++11 standard library has a symbol `ecodes` in it,

Comment: Thank you for the question edit. Have an upvote!

Comment: `ENOKEY` is the problem - it's a macro in `<errno.h>`, defined as 126 - see answer below. In future please make sure to provide a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`ENOKEY` is an error code defined in `<errno.h>`:

```
#define ENOKEY      126 /* Required key not available */
```

Presumably `<errno.h>` is being `#include`d by `<iostream>` on your build platform (at least when `-std=c++11` is specified), so the line:

```
enum ecodes { ENOKEY = -1, EDUPKEY = -2 };
```

gets preprocessed to:

```
enum ecodes { 126 = -1, EDUPKEY = -2 };
```

Hence the error.

Note: your original example code had `INVALID` in place of `ENOKEY`, so no one else was able to reproduce the problem.

Take home message: when asking questions always provide a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with *actual code that reproduces the error*, not an approximation of where you think the problems lies.